# Get records of last 2 months (current year), and last month(last year)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get records of last 2 months and last month(last year) based on my table field paidDate, using SQL server 2016.

Suppose, I run the query on Feb 1st/2nd, 2020. I need the monthly data from December 2019, January 2020, as well as January 2019.

What's the SQL query for this? Is it possible to club all of these scenario into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the logic as below-

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE 
(
    YEAR(paidDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(MM,-1, getdate())) 
    AND 
    MONTH(paidDate) =  MONTH(DATEADD(MM,-1, getdate()))
)
OR
(
    YEAR(paidDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(MM,-2, getdate())) 
    AND 
    MONTH(paidDate) =  MONTH(DATEADD(MM,-2, getdate()))
)
OR
(
    YEAR(paidDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(MM,-13, getdate())) 
    AND 
    MONTH(paidDate) =  MONTH(DATEADD(MM,-13, getdate()))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Then for the previous 2 months the paidDate would be :
A)  Higher or equal than the first day of 2 months ago
B) Lower than the first day of the current month.

Similar for the month of a year ago.

So try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE 
( 
      paidDate >= DATEADD(month, -2, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GetDate()), 0))
  AND paidDate <  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GetDate()), 0)
)
OR
( 
      paidDate >= DATEADD(month, -13, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GetDate()), 0))
  AND paidDate <  DATEADD(year, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GetDate()), 0))
)
```

Comment: @PukarAharya . . . This is a much better approach because the `WHERE` conditions can make use of an index on `(paiddate)`.

Answer (score 1):

LukStorm has the better answer in terms of performance (and I've upvoted it).  But if you want complete months and don't care about indexing, then I would suggest `datediff()`:

```
where datediff(month, paiddate, getdate()) in (1, 2, 13)
```

This gets the complete months that are 1 month, 2 months, and 13 months in the past.

Comment: I like this one for it's simplicity, very nice for this situation (2 seperate ranges).  And often such datetime fields don't get indexed anyway.  +1